# When is a C# class with no methods poor design?

Tags: c#, oop, class-design

When is a class with no methods poor design?

From what I've read, a class with no methods (i.e. no behaviors) (AKA dumb class) is poor design, with the exception of Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).  This is due to the purpose of DTOs being to reduce the overhead when transferring data to a remote interface ([Local DTO](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki//LocalDTO.html)).  There appears to be some debate on DTOs and Plain Old Class Object ([POCO VS DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto/725365#725365)) and debate going further to anemic design ([Anemic Model Domain](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)).

So, where the dumb class in question is a local object (i.e. not for transferring data) are you generally better to refactor the attributes of the dumb class and implement them as a collection (e.g. Dictionary)?  To quote Bill K ([How can i write DAOs for resources with extensible properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783198/how-can-i-write-daos-for-resources-with-extensible-properties)),
"Where you would have used an object, use a hashtable. For your attribute names use keys, for the attribute values, use the value in the hashtable."

My thinking when designing this dumb class was that of composition.  Another class is composed of multiple dumb class objects (i.e. a collection of dumb class objects).  Was my thinking wrong?  If I am to implement the dumb class as a collection, I would have a collection of a collection of attributes.

I am of the understanding collections of collections of collections etc. is also poor design.  Is there some guiding principle to balance these apparent choices of poor design?

As always any insight or guidance is appreciated.

Regards
Shannon

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 [POCO vs DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725348/poco-vs-dto/725365#725365) "A POCO follows the rules of OOP. It should (but doesn't have to) have state and behavior"

Comment: `Where you would have used an object, use a hashtable` - I'm sorry that is nonsense. Dictionaries are magic-string based, prone to all sorts of subtle errors, and also require additional casting of everything. That cannot be compared to the simplicity and beauty of a strongly typed object model. Whoever said that is either not thinking in terms of strongly typed languages such as C# or doesn't really understand OOP in general.

Comment: Additionally, `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,object>>>` that sucks. a LOT. The amount of nested generics plus the amount of casting stuff to other stuff and redundant type checks you need will turn your otherwise "simple properties" into an horrible behemoth monstrosity. Use a strongly typed object model. Always.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a class has no logic, then that would be considered a data-structure.  For the question about whether to use a generic collection vs a type, I would choose creating types because of their expressiveness.

Take the following example.

```
var employee = new Dictionary<string, object>();
employee["FirstName"] = "Steve";
employee["LastName"] = "McQueen";
employee["DOB"] = new DateTime(1942, 1, 5);
employee["Salary"] = 215000m;
```

Here you have the problem of

- being [Stringly Typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped)
- unable to implement logic within the "employee"
- no possibility of being [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)
- not being able to refactor

Contrast this with.

```
var employee = new Employee {
    FirstName = "Steve",
    LastName = "McQueen",
    DOB = new DateTime(1942, 1, 5),
    Salary = 215000m
};
```

You get the benefit of

- being able to find references of employee
- subclass employee
- refactor employee (rename `DOB` to `DateOfBirth` without having to do a search and replace)
- make properties immutable
- compile time checking
- add domain logic if ever needed
- can impose invariants

Though the one downside to this is that you have to define a class, which means more typing, though I feel the benefits *greatly* outweigh the costs.

To elaborate on my examples above, suppose you wrote a method from a repository that returned an employee.

```
var employee = employeeRepository.GetById(25);
```

If `employee` were a dictionary in this example, I would have no Intellisense to know which attributes an employee has, let alone their types, this is also illustrated by @HighCore's comment.  The only ways to determine this is to either

- read the documentation (probably out-of-date or inaccurate)
- execute the method and inspect with debugger (a waste of time and might not be possible in every scenario)

In the scenario of persisting a new `employee`, the dictionary runs into the same pitfalls and now you're at the peril of hoping the method you just executed returns meaningful error messages.

Comment: `new Date(...)` - there's no such thing in C#. your code does not compile.

Comment: +1. In addition to all this, it is important to mention that given a `List<Employee> employees` you can do things like `var richest = employees.Where(x => x.Salary > 500000)` and the like, whereas using a dictionary will complicate everything much more.

Comment: Interesting to find +3 For a comment +1'ing a +1 answer (+2 after my +1)!